# Is [tag:bash-history] a synonym for [tag:history]?

Tags: discussion

[bash-history](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/bash-history)

> Refers to the history of commands that have been run previously in Bash.

---

[history](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/history)

> The history command can be used to retrieve commands you have previously typed in a shell.

---

I think the former could count as a synonym to the latter, however [history](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/history) refers to *a shell* in general – is this distinction important enough to keep these tags separated?
If so, doesn't every question tagged [bash-history](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/bash-history) also need to be tagged [history](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/history) then?

Comment: You are assuming that tags are rationally organized and inherit from each other. Unfortunately, neither of those is the case.  But yes, we do want the pure `history` tag since `bash-history` isn't applicable t questions about zsh, sh, ksh, csh, fish etc., etc.

Comment: @terdon No doubt we do want the `history` tag, but do we also want a `bash-history` tag?

Comment: Yes, maybe not.