# Tag synonym request [fc] -> [history]

Tags: discussion, tags

Consider the description for [history](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/history):

> The history command can be used to retrieve commands you have previously typed in a shell.

However, `fc` and related variables `FCEDIT` and `HISTSIZE` exist in `bash`. There's no specific shell mentioned (which arguably might be implied to be [bash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/bash)), but [`fc`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/utilities/fc.html) is POSIX utility  and `hist` is used on Korn shell variants (which is very close to `bash`); considering that we don't have that big of a following for other shells, they still are available, and it would make sense to include that as tag synonym for [history](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/history).

As per terdon's [comment](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/17461/is-tagbash-history-a-synonym-for-taghistory#comment36281_17461) on related question, which haven't gained much attention,

> You are assuming that tags are rationally organized and inherit from each other. Unfortunately, neither of those is the case. But yes, we do want the pure history tag since bash-history isn't applicable t questions about zsh, sh, ksh, csh, fish etc., etc.

As I mentioned before, the portions involved with history mechanism occurs in other shells. Plus I think other shell users can figure out what works for `bash` and non-`bash` shell. So I'd say `fc` is a rational enough synonym.

Comment: I don't see anything tagged as `fc`.  In fact, I don't really think there's any need for an `fc` tag or a synonym to `history`.  Is something actually *using* `fc` as a tag?  Creating synonyms "Just because" is usually not a reason to create a synonym...

Comment: @ThomasWard Fair point, I guess.